# Cannot convert from 'string' to 'system.collections.generic.list string'

Tags: c#, string, list, typeconverter

I have the two list

1. nested list of string, and
2. list in string

In `index` list, I want to add `linesOfContent`with a `common` value and in-between i want to add separate string `":"`.

For that i write a code, but, I face a problem "cannot convert from 'string' to 'system.collections.generic.list string'". How to solve this.

```
int common = 10;
List<List<string>> index = new List<List<string>>();
List<int> linesOfContent = new List<int>();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
      for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
      {       
             linesOfContent.Add(i+":"+common);
      }
      index.Add(linesOfContent);
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
index[0][0] = 0:10
index[0][1] = 1:10
index[0][2] = 2:10
```

...
...

Comment: Can you show the expected results inside `index ` List ?

Comment: @shad0wk I want a result as in expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `List` of `Lists` of string should contain `Lists` of `string`, not `Lists` of `int`.

```
int common = 10;
List<List<string>> index = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> linesOfContent = new List<string>();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {       
        linesOfContent.Add(i.ToString() +":"+common.ToString());
    }
    index.Add(linesOfContent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each item in your `index` list is a `List<string>`. When you try to add an item, it should be a List. However, you're trying to add a string to it, `linesOfContent+":"+common` is considered a string.

**Solution:**

Linq's `Select` Method (aka Projection) can be used to transform each element inside a sequence:

```
index.Add(linesOfContent.Select(x=> x.ToString()  + ":" + common).ToList());
```

Be aware that the way you're constructing your loops results in some duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code, without the foreach loops, instead it uses `Enumerable.Range`:

```
linesOfContent.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(i => i.ToString() + ":" + common.ToString()).ToArray());
index.Add(linesOfContent);
```